# I need to remove a pre-loader from a website

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress site. The theme I purchased has the functionality to spin a pre-loader image until the site is fully loaded. I want to remove that from the front page because it will frustrated my customers and they will think that the site is broken or something else like that. The preloader is configured with jQuery or Ajax(I am not sure). Can anyone please help me to remove that or at least inform me how I can remove that? 
Site is :http://www.beverlyhillsconstruction.com/

Here's the link of theme's functions.php: [Google Drive Link for functions.php](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9ySM2rXjM37NVlDUUJ1bzU0MkU)

[image: Here is the pre-loader image:]

Comment: suggest you check with the theme developer. This isn't a website troubleshooting service

Comment: I know that this isn't a troubleshooting service but I want to learn how to remove that. If you can't help, then please don't put any irrelevant comment.

Comment: You are expected to post all relevant code in the question itself, not just a link to a website, along with a code related problem See [mcve]

Comment: You need to deregister the spinner scripts. Without code it's hard to help. Look at your functions.php (in the theme folder) and copy it in your question. With a little bit of Luck (the piece of code for the spinner will be there) we'll be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @Benoti for your kind help. I have attached the functions.php file. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Ok, i'm with my mobile, it's hard but: in the glammy_script function glammy_theme_scripts_styles you have different js link, try to comment lines begins by wp_enqueue_script one by one and test. As the developper not explicitly comment his code, i don't know which js load the spinner. When you have find the file, we'll be able to fix it with remove_action (and rewrite a function) or deregister the script with wp_deregister_script (but de need to know which script to deregister )

Comment: Ow man, that's a great help. That's the way to check for functions and bugs. I always find help in Stackoverflow, he he he. Thanks for your help buddy. 1 upvote for you :) (y)

Answer (score 1):

After a quick view on the source code, it seems to me that the preloader is embed in the file myscript.js, that you can dequeue easily in the functions.php like this :

```
wp_dequeue_script( 'myscript' );
```

But, unfortunately, it's not easy to do, this because this file contains other jquery functions.

You need to make a child theme to update your theme without thinking about all modifications you've already done. It's easy and will not change anything about your options setted. [Why use child-theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

After this, you'll be able to do this in the child-theme functions files.
Copy / paste myscript.js into child-theme/js/ and name it my-new-script.js.
Remove preloader part (nearly at the top of the file):

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout("jQuery('#preloader').animate({'opacity' : '0'},300,function(){jQuery('#preloader').hide()})", 800);
    setTimeout("jQuery('.preloader_hide, .selector_open').animate({'opacity' : '1'},500)", 800);
});
```

In the functions.php file :

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se_40563443', 99);

    function se_40563443(){
         wp_dequeue_script( 'myscript' );

         wp_enqueue_script('glammy-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/my-new-script.js', array, false, true);
    }
```

You can do it with the parent theme but every custom code will be erase with any update.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I found the preloader function. It's in the starting of myscript.js. I will remove it and the part which is connected with that preloader. Thanks again :)